# what is the appropriate way to edit two different objects based on if statement?

Tags: r, if-statement, apply

I want to edit a column of a df only if a condition is met by a second column and also keep track of when the condition is false. What is the appropriate way to do this?

I have tried using `ifelse()` but both the true and false code is always executed. Plus, it seems like the wrong approach since I do not want the `ifelse` vector output. (Here I only want to evaluate the first row of each ID).

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1,2,3), each = 2), value = rep(c(4,7,-8), 
each = 2), new_val = rep(0, each=6))

neg_val <- vector()

ifelse(df[!duplicated(df$id), "value"] > 0,
    df[!duplicated(df$id), "new_val"] <- df[!duplicated(df$id),"value"], 
    neg_val <- append(neg_val, df[!duplicated(df$id), "id"]))

[1] 4 7 3
> neg_val
[1] 1 2 3
```

The output of the `ifelse` is as I expected, the positive values or the ID of negative values. But the `df` is updated for all values, not just when `value > 0` and `neg_val` includes all the IDs when I only wanted the IDs for `values =< 0`. Desired output:

```
> df
  id value new_val
1  1     4       4
2  1     4       0
3  2     7       7
4  2     7       0
5  3    -8       0
6  3    -8       0
> neg_val
[1] 3
```

Comment: Don't you want the first row of duplicates get updated in `new_val`? That's what I get. Please clarify. The best would be adding your desired output of `df` to the body of question using [edit] (not in the comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this? is that what you are looking for?

```
df[!duplicated(df$id), "new_val"]<-ifelse(df[!duplicated(df$id), "value"] > 0,
       df[!duplicated(df$id), "new_val"] <- df[!duplicated(df$id),"value"], 
       df[!duplicated(df$id), "new_val"] <- df[!duplicated(df$id),"id"])
neg_val<-ifelse(df[!duplicated(df$id), "value"] > 0,
       NA,df[!duplicated(df$id),"id"])
neg_val<-na.omit(neg_val)
```

Comment: works, but I thought there would be a way to do it without repeating the `ifelse`